# Setting SharePoint List Metadata

Tags: sharepoint, list, metadata

Metadata seems to be used frequently to describe a SharePoint list's *structure*. That structure allows the storage of data at the list *item* level.

How can I specify information about the list itself without relying on an additional column?

Ideally I want something like SPList.Properties ["Mykey"] = "MyValue"

PropertiesXml isn't settable but is there any way to alter the data it returns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no property bag on the SPList object itself, however you can use the one on [SPList.RootFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.rootfolder.aspx). Its SPFolder object has a [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.properties.aspx) property.

Comment: Works perfectly. I also needed to call update on the SPFolder object after adding a new key/value pair (didn't Update() the list).

Comment: Here's how I implemented this: http://blog.mediawhole.com/2009/07/storing-sharepoint-list-meta-data.html

Comment: Great, but that properties are not stored in list templates. So I don't know how to allow end-users to create lists with them. Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Alex' direct answer, you could store the metadata on your lists in a separate dedicated, possibly hidden, list.

Comment: This idea has a lot of merit; the only hassle is defining and provisioning the list (although a two-column name/value style list would be reusable). I'd mark this as the second answer if I could!